# Confusion about definition of differential manifold

Tags: analysis

I'm reading a spanish book which has the following definition of whats called (variedad diferenciable) that I think is the spanish name for differential manifold.

**Definition** $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ non empty. $M$ is a manifold of dimension $m$ $1 \leq m \lt n$ of class $C^q$, if for each $x^0 \in M$, there exists a open neighbourhood $W_{x^0}$ of $x^0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a function: $\phi_{x^0} \in C^q ( W_{x^0}, \mathbb{R}^{n - m})$, such that $D \phi_{x^0}(x)$ has maximum rank, $n - m$, for all $x \in W_{x^0}$ and:

$$ M \cap W_{x^0} = \{x \in W_{x^0} : \phi_{x^0}(x) = 0\}$$

The above definition is called a m-manifold.

I have found a similar definition in Wendell's Fleming book Functions of Several Variables. But I haven't found this definition anywhere else, all the definitions I find elsewhere use the concept of chart. Is the concept of chart underlying in the definition? Is it $\phi_{x^0}$?

Is this definition equivalent to the concept explained in the wikipedia page about [Differentiable manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold)?

Comment: The "chart definition" is good and it let's you deal with more abstract and general objects, but here you are dealing just with manifolds in $\Bbb R^n$ so there's no need for generality (no topological spaces, etc). The definition of your book matches with te deffinition of "Regular Submanifold" more than the definition of manifold. This means not only your space is a manifold, but it's topologycal and differential structure "behaves well" with the structure of $\Bbb R^n$ thus, a regular submanifold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is the following: to define a differentiable manifold in an abstract sense you have to put on it a differentiable atlas, consisting of charts that tell you how to put coordinates on regions of the manifold, and in such a way that the change of coordinates is as smooth as you require.

In the case you give you are not in the most abstract possible case, but rather you are already inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ which has its own standard differentiable structure. In this definition, then, it makes sense to do not ignore this fact and that is why you require the existence of a neighborhood $W_{x_0}$ *of $\mathbb{R}^n$* and a function $\phi\in C^q(W_{x_0}, \mathbb{R}^{n - m})$ with the given conditions.

When you do this, a set of open neighborhoods of $M$ appears in a natural way, and it consists of $M\cap W_{x_0}$ as $x_0$ varies. By the definition of subspace topology, these are actually open in $M$. The only thing you are missing to obtain the classical definition of chart is to understand what happens when you change of coordinates.

In order to do this you need to invoke the implicit function theorem, that guarantees you the existence of a function $g: U\subset\mathbb{R^m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n - m}$ such that $\phi_{x_0}(x, g(x)) = 0$ for any $x\in U$. And this, by the condition you put, means that $(x, g(x))$ is actually in $M$. (In here we maybe relabel the coordinates as to make the last $n - m$ correspond to those that will give you the maximal rank).

The chart thus becomes projecting onto the first $m$ coordinates and the condition of the rank and the dimension $n - m$, is to make sure that you obtain an inverse of a chart in M that can be composed with another projection, which is smooth globally, and give a differentiable map between open sets of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

The main point of this definition then, is that there exist coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that fixing the value of some of them gives you coordinates of $M$ and so you get, varying the possible fixing values, layers of diffeomorphic subsets (like sheets one on top of another).

The reason why you don't see this as the standard definition of manifold is because in order to do this you need $M$ to be inside another manifold $N$ to begin with, so that it makes sense to talk about a neighborgood in $N$ (what we called $W_{x_0})$. This concept appears after we have defined differentiable structures and is the concept of regular submanifold. To see the difference, think of the x axis and of the graph of the absolute value as sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Abstractly, as sets, these two admit a differentiable structure, but as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ only the $x-$axis is a regular submanifold.